# What does operator % mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, operators

I want to know what the Haskell operator % does. It is hard to find on google, I could not find it in the Haskell Report either.

I saw it used in this piece of code:

```
 fi=zz.bu
 bu=zz.(:).(++"zz")
 []#zz=zz;zz#__=zz
 zZ%zz=zZ zz$zZ%zz
 zz=(([[],[]]++).)
 zZ=zipWith;z=zZ((#).show)[1..]$zZ(++)(bu%"Fi")(fi%"Bu")
```

taken from: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88/obfuscated-fizzbuzz-golf/110#110

Comment: It's not built in - that code defines it as `zZ%zz=zZ zz$zZ%zz`, and it has type `(t -> t1 -> t1) -> t -> t1`

Comment: I can define it myself like this for example?: a%b = a+b ? Cool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is [the relevant section](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-240003.2) of the Haskell Report:

> Haskell provides special syntax to support infix notation. An operator is a function that can be applied using infix syntax (Section 3.4), or partially applied using a section (Section 3.5).
>
> An operator is either an operator symbol, such as `+` or `$$`, or is an ordinary identifier enclosed in grave accents (backquotes), such as `op`. For example, instead of writing the prefix application `op x y`, one can write the infix application `` x `op` y ``. If no fixity declaration is given for `` `op` `` then it defaults to highest precedence and left associativity (see Section 4.4.2).
>
> Dually, an operator symbol can be converted to an ordinary identifier by enclosing it in parentheses. For example, `(+) x y` is equivalent to `x + y`, and `foldr (*) 1 xs` is equivalent to `foldr (\x y -> x * y) 1 xs`.

That is to say, there is nothing special about "operators" in Haskell other than their syntax. A function whose name is made from symbols defaults to infix, a function whose name is alphanumeric defaults to prefix, and either can be used in the other style with a bit of extra syntax.

Incidentally, since it's often impossible to search based on operator names using Google, to find operators that are declared in the standard libraries there are two [search engines](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) specifically for [finding things](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) on Hackage.

Answer (score 5):

In general, we can define a new function `foo` like so:

```
foo a b c = (something involving a, b, and c)
```

Similarly, we can define a binary operator `%` (constructed out of any combination of symbol characters) like so:

```
a % b = (something involving a and b)
```